# Trigger not firing on dynamic added fields

Tags: parsley.js

I have a form with some input fields

`<form data-parsley-validate="true" data-parsley-trigger="focusout">
  <input required="required" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" type="text" name="order[first_name]">
  ...`

if leave the input field it gets validated

on click you can add some more input fields with `data-parsley-trigger="focusout">`

if I now leave these new added input fields they dont get validated.
however if I click on submit they get validated.

so only the trigger isnt working on newly added fields.
how can I get this working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of Parsley (2.8+):

```
// Add your field...
// and because your field can't wait until next validation:
$('.your-form').parsley().refresh()
```